# media query cant get to work for IE any version

Tags: css, html, media-queries

Been playing around with media queries and thought I understood how it worked.

I have the following code in my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 0px)" href="mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 350px)" href="tablet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1050px)" href="screen.css">
```

Basically using a different css stylesheet depending on the size of the screen.

Works great with firefox and chrome.  Doesn't work at all with IE.
Not even with version 11 that I downloaded today.
In fact IE appears to ignore all the link's and no styling at all is applied.
Have tried for versions 8 and 9 but same problem.

Any one know the reason for this ? Is there a syntax difference for IE ?

Comment: Cause of problem.  Buggy IE11.
It was using version IE7 of IE from my komodo editor.
Not sure why this occurred.  
Perhaps it keeps settings based on the last visited website ?
 I think the debugging tools are a little bit buggy at the moment.  I got the whole browser to crash when I tried to look at the network traffic tab.

Answer (score 2):

Use [css3-mediaqueries-js](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js). This library emulates media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the `link` elements, Internet Explorer is (rightly) a stickler for proper HTML so it might be that.

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 0px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 350px)" href="tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1050px)" href="screen.css" />
```